# What is the name of the literary technique/device used where the reader is only shown one side of a dialogue?

Tags: poetry, literary-techniques, dialogue, literary-device

What is the literary device used when there is a dialogue but only one speaker's side is heard/shown to the reader/audience. And how can I write this in a way that it is clear that although this person is talking to someone else, and that person is responding, that the words present belong only to one speaker?

Comment: halfalogue is a noun - not sure of lit. technique.

Comment: Obligatory [Bob Newhart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EImgHuqQsuk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquially, this is the equivalent of hearing one side of a conversation. Sensibly, scriptwriter John August calls this a **one-sided dialogue** in [a blog post](https://johnaugust.com/2008/one-sided-dialogue) titled, well, "One-sided dialogue."

Editor Deena Nataf calls it the same thing [in a post of her own](https://blog.bookbaby.com/2016/06/writing-phone-conversations/):

> When writing phone conversations, does your **one-sided dialogue** give insight into the character of one or both participants or the relationship between them?

Heck, even scholars use the collocation. Michael von Albrecht, [writing about ancient Roman forms of discourse](https://books.google.com/books?id=DrYatgm2MWoC&pg=PA505&lpg=PA505&dq=%22one-sided%20dialogue%22%20literature&source=bl&ots=2Z8bxAIK1G&sig=ACfU3U13_WEFPdoorn3-7pqVfZv5VNArEQ&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAweqQkcDlAhWGdd8KHcUpA1IQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), uses *'one-sided' dialogue* as a suitable coinage to describe Seneca:

> A distinction may be drawn between the didactic poem (s. above), the didactic monograph concentrating on one theme and using literary means to reach a wider audience (e.g. Cic. *off*.), the philosophical dialogue (several times in Cicero), the **'one-sided' dialogue**, intended for self-instruction or as edifying reading (Seneca's writings) ...